# How to set the location.state of a route before the popstate event?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

When I'm on page B and hit the browser back button to got to page A, I'd like to be able to use `history.replaceState` to update the state of page B before actually going to page A. That way, if the user presses forward they will see what they last saw from page B.

I've tried doing this in the window popstate event, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: could use sessionStorage for the state. or does it explicitly need to use history api

Comment: I'm using react-router v4 which html5 routing using the history package. But that all uses the history api under the hood